# How to create a file in a specific directory in Rubymine/PHPStorm/other JetBrains IDEs without leaving the home row

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, rubymine

Currently, I am doing the following:

1. <kbd>cmd-1</kbd> to go to the project structure view
2. Move to the arrow keys (not on the home row - I want to avoid this step), or, (horrors!) the mouse to navigate to the folder I want to create the file in
3. <kbd>ctrl-alt-n</kbd> to open the new file dialogue, which always created the file in the selected directory

Is there a better way to specify/move to the directory without having to use the arrow keys/mouse so that I can stay on the home row?

I have tried:

- Moving to the root of the project structure pane using <kbd>pageup</kbd>and typing the name of the directory - this is good, but <kbd>pageup</kbd> is way off the home row. Also it often selects the wrong folder (e.g. the one in `/spec`, not the one in `/app`) and I can only get to the right one with the arrow keys again. There seems to be no way to type `app/controllers` as it doesn't process the slash as a directory separator for some reason.
- Using the navigation bar via <kbd>option-pageup</kbd>, moving all the way left with the <kbd>left arrow</kbd>, then either navigating to the right directory with other arrow keys, or using <kbd>ctrl-alt-n</kbd> from the roor and typing the full path, but this is also way off the home row and no faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> if you are using Linux/Windows keymap) to open the [*Navigate to file*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html#d1569081e18546) dialog (or hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to open the [*Search Everywhere*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/searching-everywhere.html) dialog).

Type the name of the directory you want to create the file in. Note that the directory name must end with `/` in order for IntelliJ to know that you want to open a directory not a file.

You can type just part of the path, such as `webapp/resources/`

[image]

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the selected directory will be opened in Project view.

Then you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>) to create new file as usual.

Comment: Sweet! Just tried and it works with the even simpler double <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> press, then the new file shortcut. Thanks!